# Error Output for substr

Tags: c++

I got a code. It supposes to give me an output for the number of count everytime it found "code", "cope", "coze", "cole", or "core". for example: countCode("aaacodebbb") it should be 1, but found 0.

```
int countCode(const string& inStr) {
    int count = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < inStr.length(); i++) {
        if (inStr.substr(i,i+3) == "code" || inStr.substr(i,i+3) == "coze" || inStr.substr(i,i+3) == "cope" || inStr.substr(i,i+3) == "core" || inStr.substr(i,i+3) == "cole") {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing (or inspecting in a debugger) `inStr.substr(i,i+3)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

That second argument is meant to be the *length,* not the final character position. You need to use `inStr.substr(i,4)` instead.

In addition, you *know* that a four-character string cannot occur when there's less than four characters remaining in the string, so you can make it more logical (and possibly mire efficient) with something like:

```
int countCode (const string& inStr) {
    int count = 0;
    size_t len = inStr.length();
    if (len >= 4) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= len - 4; i++) {
            if (inStr.substr(i,4) == "code" || ... ) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also note the use of `size_t` which is the more natural type for handling sizes and positions in strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you check e.g. [this `substr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) you will see that the second argument is the length of the sub-string, not the ending position.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is the count, not the end position.

```
basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0,
                 size_type count = npos ) const;
```

**Parameters**

```
    pos      -   position of the first character to include
    count    -   length of the substring
    ^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That means, you should use

```
inStr.substr(i,4)
```